# Failed GRUB menu Dual boot with Kali Linux

Tags: linux, windows, multi-boot, grub, kali-linux

Please help me I am really panicking. I installed Kali linux as a dual boot while following all the steps on the docs.kali website, it worked! But when I reached the GRUB menu I could only see Kali OS and not my original windows OS, when I logged into Kali I looked at Gparted and saw that my Windows drive was still there with all its data, but how do I boot into windows now. I really need help urgently and I have no idea what to do.

Comment: Welcome on SuperUser. Please add the link to the instruction page you followed and some details more about what you did. A single click can make the difference on what you did... BTW all should be still there, and it will probably result that you have to add a line to GRUB...

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer as I was trying to reply to your comment Hastur, so... Thanks!!

I had to go to the Terminal and run

```
sudo os-prober
```

And it detected my Windows 10 system, then I ran:

```
sudo update-grub
```

And then I restarted and found Windows 10 bootable, with all my data and working just as slow as earlier (Linux made me expect fast shutdown and boot speed, Windows 10's boot and shutdown speed made me lose faith in Windows)